# Gridview DataSourceID with Multiple Datasources?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, gridview

I would like to display clickable news headlines.  But I'm having trouble pulling data from two datasources for a single GridView.  I'm trying to do this DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1, SqlDataSource2"  but that's not working.  Thanks in advance.

```
<asp:GridView 
        ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1, SqlDataSource2" 
        >   
       <Columns>
           <asp:HyperLinkField  
            DataTextField = "NewsHeadline" 
            DataNavigateUrlFields="NewsURL"
          />
       </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="
<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString1 %>"
       ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString1.ProviderName %>" 
       SelectCommand="SELECT [NewsHeadline] FROM [NewsTable]">
   </asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="
<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString1 %>"
       ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString1.ProviderName %>" 
       SelectCommand="SELECT [NewsURL] FROM [NewsTable]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single control cannot use multiple sources.

You could create a custom data source control that accepts two data sources and produces output from both of them.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an SQL query that will select those 2 columns?
Like:

```
SELECT [NewsHeadline], [NewsURL] FROM [NewsTable] WHERE 'something'
```

This way You will have one Datasource and problem will be solved :)